# How can I get the Reverent ball throwing style?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

To get the Reverent ball throwing style, I have to "spend some time with a romanticist." I'm not sure how to do this.

Who is the NPC, where can I find them, and how do I "spend time" with them?

Comment: Hi Phoenix. I edited your post rather heavily to try and make it flow better--you mention knowing where the NPC is, but then ask for it a sentence later. Please feel free to undo any of the changes I made, as you see fit. :-)

Comment: Ehehehe. . . I'm sorry for the trouble XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Serebii you will have to Defeat Kiawe in battle in Paniola Town (Sun) OR
Defeat Mallow in battle in Lush Jungle (Moon)
This must be done after completing the Island's (Akala) Grand Trial, not just the Trainer's regular Trial encounter.

[Serebii Source](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/battlestyle.shtml) Check this link for more battlestyles

Comment: Already fought with Mallow in Lush Jungle. Is there a second battle or something?

Comment: Maybe finishing the game aswell. Couldn't find any additional information on it

Comment: @Phoenix You don't have to beat the game, but it is a second fight available after completing their Island's grand Trial.